# BigQueryIO Read performance using withTemplateCompatibility

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Apache Beam 2.1.0 had a bug with template pipelines that read from BigQuery which meant they could only be executed once. More details here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2058

This has been fixed with the release of Beam 2.2.0, you can now read from BigQuery using the **withTemplateCompatibility** option, your template pipeline can now be run multiple times.

```
  pipeline
    .apply("Read rows from table."
         , BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                     .withTemplateCompatibility()
                     .from("<your-table>")
                     .withoutValidation())
```

This implementation seems to come with a huge performance cost to BigQueryIO read operation, I now have batch pipelines what ran in **8-11 minutes** now consistently taking **45-50 minutes** to complete. The only difference between both pipelines is the **.withTemplateCompatibility()**.

Am trying to understand the reasons for the huge drop in performance and if there is any way to improve them.

Thanks.

**Solution:** based on jkff's input.

```
  pipeline
    .apply("Read rows from table."
         , BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                     .withTemplateCompatibility()
                     .from("<your-table>")
                     .withoutValidation())
    .apply("Reshuffle",  Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this is due to the fact that `withTemplateCompatibility` comes at the cost of disabling [dynamic rebalancing](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/no-shard-left-behind-dynamic-work-rebalancing-in-google-cloud-dataflow) for this read step.

I would expect it to have significant impact only if you're reading a small or moderate amount of data, but performing very heavy processing on it. In this case, try adding a `Reshuffle.viaRandomKey()` onto your `BigQueryIO.read()`. It will materialize a temporary copy of the data, but will parallelize downstream processing much better.

Comment: Thanks, jkff. This resolves the issue, but I see that the Reshuffle transformation is marked as deprecated and for internal use.

Comment: It's in an unfortunate place where we know that it'll need a replacement (hence deprecated) but we don't have one yet :( you can safely use it for now.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "It will materialize a temporary copy of the data"? Thanks!

Comment: It means that it will not just read data from BigQuery and immediately process it by your transforms, but it will make a temporary copy of the data from BigQuery onto GCS, and read from that copy.