# Google cloud dataflow : Shutting down JVM after 8 consecutive periods of measured GC thrashing

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Am using google cloud dataflow to do some transformation

am treading about 3 million records from GBQ and performing a transformation and writing transform result to GCS.

While doing this operation dataflow is failing with error 
Error : 
Shutting down JVM after 8 consecutive periods of measured GC thrashing

Workflow failed. Causes: S20:Read GBQ/Reshuffle.ViaRandomKey/Reshuffle/GroupByKey/Read+Read GBQ/Reshuffle.ViaRandomKey/Reshuffle/GroupByKey/GroupByWindow+Read GBQ/Reshuffle.ViaRandomKey/Reshuffle/ExpandIterable+Read GBQ/Reshuffle.ViaRandomKey/Values/Values/Map+Read GBQ/ReadFiles+Read GBQ/PassThroughThenCleanup/ParMultiDo(Identity)+Read GBQ/PassThroughThenCleanup/View.AsIterable/ParDo(ToIsmRecordForGlobalWindow)+transform+Split results/ParMultiDo(Partition)+Write errors/WriteFiles/RewindowIntoGlobal/Window.Assign+Write errors/WriteFiles/WriteShardedBundlesToTempFiles/ApplyShardingKey+Write errors/WriteFiles/WriteShardedBundlesToTempFiles/GroupIntoShards/Reify+Write errors/WriteFiles/WriteShardedBundlesToTempFiles/GroupIntoShards/Write+Write entities Gzip/WriteFiles/WriteShardedBundlesToTempFiles/ApplyShardingKey+Write entities Gzip/WriteFiles/WriteShardedBundlesToTempFiles/GroupIntoShards/Reify+Write entities Gzip/WriteFiles/WriteShardedBundlesToTempFiles/GroupIntoShards/Write failed., A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on:

DataConverterOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(DataConverterOptions.class);
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

```
    EntityCreatorFn entityCreatorFn = EntityCreatorFn.newWithGCSMapping(options.getMapping(),
            options.getWithUri(), options.getLineNumberToResult(), options.getIsPartialUpdate(), options.getQuery() != null);
    PCollectionList<String> resultByType =
            p.apply("Read GBQ", BigQueryIO.read(
                    (SchemaAndRecord elem) -> elem.getRecord().get("lineNumber") + "|" + elem.getRecord().get("sourceData"))
                    .fromQuery(options.getQuery()).withoutValidation()
                    .withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of()).withTemplateCompatibility()).apply("transform",ParDo.of(entityCreatorFn))
                    .apply("Split results",Partition.of(2, (Partition.PartitionFn<String>) (elem, numPartitions) -> {
                        if (elem.startsWith(PREFIX_ERROR)) {
                            return PARTITION_ERROR;
                        }
                        return PARTITION_SUCCESS;
                    }));
    FileIO.Sink sink = TextIO.sink();
    resultByType.get(0).apply("Write entities Gzip", FileIO.write().to(options.getOutput()).withCompression(Compression.GZIP).withNumShards(options.getShards()).via(sink));
    resultByType.get(1).apply("Write errors", TextIO.write().to(options.getErrorOutput()).withoutSharding());
    p.run();
```

Shutting down JVM after 8 consecutive periods of measured GC thrashing. Memory is used/total/max = 109/301/2507 MB, GC last/max = 54.00/54.00 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=true.

Answer (score 0):

Does 'EntityCreatorFn.newWithGCSMapping' cache elements in memory by any chance ? Seems like one of the steps in your pipeline is consuming too much memory (note that Dataflow cannot parallelize processing of a single element of a DoFn). I suggest adjusting your pipeline or trying out highmem machines. If the problem persists, please consider contacting [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) with relevant job IDs etc.

Comment: Issue was with withTemplateCompatibility() for BigQueryIO.read
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755692/bigqueryio-read-performance-using-withtemplatecompatibility helped me solve the issue.

Since there were no parallel processing 1 worker thread was not enough and failed with OOM, With reshuffling number of worker threads increased and job completed successfully.
 
Still few threads failed with OOM but jobs were re-run for failed part.
 Increased heap memory to stops jobs failing with OOM

thanks